# How to share an instance created in main with a class in another module

Tags: python, class, share, instance, global

I am having a problem with how to share a class instance between modules. Below is not the actual code, it is a simplified representation of what I'm trying to do. The variable in question is thePlot. If I make it a global, I get 'global name not defined' type errors. If I don't use a global, then the 'draw' method in the shapes modules can't find it.

I get errors when the draw() method is called and it tries to execute the 'thePlot' method 'plot'.

```
* Main module *****************
import matplotlib as plt
import plotter
import shapes

main():
    thePlot = plotter.plotter()
    cyl = shapes.cylinder(r, c, n, color)
    cyl.draw()
    plt.show()

* shapes module *******************
import main
import plotter

class shapes(self):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def cylinder(r, c, n, color):
    self.r = r
    self.c = c
    self.n = n
    self.color = color

def draw(self):
    self.x = calculate list of x coordinates
    self.y = calculate list of y coordinates
    self.z = calculate list of z coordinates
    global thePlot
    * This line causes the error
    thePlot.plot(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.color)

* plotter module ******************
import matplotlib as plt

class plotter(self):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    def plot(self, x, y, z, color):
        self.ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* Main module *****************
import matplotlib as plt
import plotter
import shapes

def main():
    global thePlot
    thePlot = plotter.plotter()
    cyl = shapes.cylinder(r, c, n, color)
    cyl.draw()
    plt.show()
```

And this:

```
global thePlot
* This line causes the error
thePlot.plot(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.color)
```

Should become:

```
main.thePlot.plot(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.color)
```

With the condition that `main.main()` was called before.

Comment: Then I get an 'Undefined variable from import: thePlot' error.

Comment: @TomSpargo this looks like a PyDev error. It doesn't mean that the script will not work. To make `main.thePlot` work  at the time of usage it must exist, i.e. either you must have already called `main.main` function or do `thePlot = plotter.plotter()` not inside `main.main()` but at the module level.

Comment: Yes, if I put thePlot = plotter.plotter before the if __name__ == 'main... statement then it works. I think this is called a singleton object. This is what I'll do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with matplotlib, but it looks like there is a similar question [Add cylinder to plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26989131/4293747) .  How about this adapted code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

"""
def cyl():
    x = None
    y = None
    z = None
    return
"""
def cyl():
    x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
    z=np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
    Xc, Zc=np.meshgrid(x, z)
    Yc = np.sqrt(1-Xc**2)
    return Xc, Yc, Zc

Xc, Yc, Zc = cyl()

#draw parameters                                                                                                                                                          
rstride = 20
cstride = 10
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, rstride=rstride, cstride=cstride)
ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, rstride=rstride, cstride=cstride)

ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is more about how to share an instance between modules than a Matplotlib question.