# plot a cylinder in python

Tags: python, plot, 3d

I am trying to plot a full cylinder, using a cylindrical mesh grid.
However I just managed to get half a cylinder. Here is my code

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
r = 1
x = np.linspace(-r, r, 50)
y = np.linspace(-r, r, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = (np.pi * -Y**2)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

What I would like to obtain is something like this
[image]

Could anybody give me some insights on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989131/add-cylinder-to-plot) the ax.plot_surface function is called twice. In your case adding a minus sign to the Z does not yet result in a cylinder, but at least you have a top and bottom part.